# Docker fails to create default machine - Raw-mode is unavailable

Tags: virtualbox, docker, hyper-v

I've been trying to create a default machine via Docker Quickstart Terminal (Win 10 Home) and am encountering a whole host of issues despite the fact it was working perfectly fine a few hours ago and I don't recall making any changes.

My most recent attempt results in:

```
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V. (VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:07.380361 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
```

Hyper-V is disabled, AMD-V is enabled in BIOS, Task Manager lists virtualization as enabled, and Credential Guard is disabled. I've also had to add the *--virtualbox-no-vtx-check* option to circumvent prior issues. I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.